# Android Studio - Layout Inspector not work

Tags: android, layout-inspector

My Layout Inspector not work, just keep loading...

[like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMm6N.png)

My Android Studio is Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 1.

In the tools->SDK Manager window, "Layout Inspector Image Server for API 29-30" is installed.

I don't know why it can not load...

Comment: it will show only show layout inspection of Devices running Api26 or above and it will only show your application runed to the device

Comment: @AjayKS My device is api 30, and I had connect to my device.